# Dynamic Paint with sequence of colors as brush

Tags: dynamic-paint, dynamic

I want to paint a sequence of colors dynamically onto an object.
In the blender docs under the category Dynamic Paint > Paint there is an example image that shows a sequence of colors painted on a surface. In the settings of the brush I can only draw a single color.
[Blender Docs Image](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/dynamic_paint/canvas.html#paint)
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have e.g. a plane as canvas, you can make e.g. two objects (or even more) as brushes. If you give them a different color, you can get this:

[image]

[image]

Shading nodes of the plane:

[image]

You can of course animate/keyframe the brush/paint color.

[image]

result:

[image]

for color by distance feature you can use this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

although the animated gif looks a bit weird here (the white stripe isn't really white) but if you follow my node setup it works.

Comment: but can I change the color based on the traveled distance instead of the shading nodes of the plane?
I want this to be like a pen that is filled with different colors that releases the colors in the given order, independent of the surface.

Comment: just animate/keyframe the brush color. I updated my answer

Comment: ah! great, I didn't know that the color value could be keyframed, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome